# How does Python run module code when there's no matching .pyc file?

Tags: python, bytecode

If I import a module1.py from the python command line in windows 7 I see the corresponding module1.pyc file appear in the Python32/**pycache**/ folder.  My understanding was that it is this bytecode which is executed by the Python interpreter, however I can delete the module1.pyc file and my module functions (module1.func1() etc...) can still be called from the command line.  What is running when the functions are called but the .pyc file is not there?  When the bytecode is compiled is it also copied to runtime memory for the Python shell?

Comment: You can run python with `-B` or `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE='any non-empty string`

Answer (score 5):

The bytecode is in memory while running the interpreter. The .pyc files are a cache for the next import of the code, so that python will not have to parse the code if it has not changed.

Answer (score 4):

#### TL;DR

Python is always running compiled byte-code, either compiled at run-time or read from a .pyc file on disk.

#### Slightly Longer Answer

Python calls [py_compile](http://docs.python.org/library/py_compile.html#module-py_compile) or [compileall](http://docs.python.org/library/compileall.html#module-compileall) when byte code compilation is needed. If valid precompiled byte code is found in a .pyc file, Python uses it. It can do this even without the original source file present.

If there's no .pyc file, or if the source file is newer than the precompiled byte code, then Python uses the source file and recompiles. That's the behavior you're observing.

#### Official Answer

For the canonical answer, see [PEP 3147: PYC Repository Directories](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#python-behavior) .

Comment: Thanks you. +1 for the PEP link and helping with all the concepts around .pyc